# Into a given circle, inscribe a triangle, given the sum of two of its sides and the angle opposite to one of them.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

[image]

I'm stuck at this problem for hours. This is from a book from Kiselev's geometry.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It is unclear what the question is asking.

Comment: The problem asks to construct the figure of given conditions. The figure above is just my interpretation to the question: it is a random figure with random given. Usually when I solve construction problem but I draw random things and study its properties to get information that might me help solve the problem. Bottom line: still haven't solve it. >.<

Comment: Can you give the exact statement of the question as it appears in your book?

Comment: The title of this post is exactly the statement of the problem from the book.

Answer (score 1):

By  drawing a tangent to the given circle, take a chord which forms with the tangent the given angle. This chord is one of the sides of the given sum. Note that all the inscribed angles intercepting the corresponding arc are congruent to the given angle. 
Let $P$ and $Q$ be the endpoints of the chord. From $P$ extend the chord outside the circle to obtain a segment $RQ$ of length equal to the given sum. Let $S$ be the intersection of the arc and the  circle centred at $P$ of radius $RP$. Then $\triangle PQS$ is the required triangle.

Comment: @tighten Any further doubt?

Comment: Yes. I got it. I was looking at it differently.

Comment: It was easier than I expected. >.<

Comment: @tighten You are welcome. Btw https://math.stackexchange.com/tour